# Jenkins Execute failed: java.io.IOException ant build

Tags: java, android, ant, hudson, jenkins

I have set up Jenkins on debianserver and I am trying to create the first  android build but ant is  not able to get invoked

In jenkins configuration I have:

```
    Name: Java6
    JAVA_HOME/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
    Name: AntHome
    ANT_HOME/usr/share/ant
```

On the job config:

```
    git  > repo
    Build step-
    Ant invoke
    Ant Version: AntHome
    Targets: -d
    build file: folder/folder/build.xml
```

When I build the job it gives me this error

```
[folder] $ /usr/share/ant/bin/ant -file build.xml -d
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/folder/folder/build.xml:47: Execute failed: \
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program \
    "/home/dims/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.0_r2/tools/aapt": \
    java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I get the same on command line

```
jenkins@host:~/workspace/Project/folder/folder$/usr/share/ant/bin/ant -d
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/folder/folder/build.xml:47: Execute failed: \
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program \
    "/home/dims/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.0_r2/tools/aapt": \
     java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

It's happening with this particular project because I have created others and ant -d works: for example

```
    jenkins@host:~$ android create project -n template -t android-10 -p Project -k some.pkg -a Some
    Created project directory: Project
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/src/some/pkg
    Added file Project/src/some/pkg/Some.java
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/res
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/bin
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/libs
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/res/values
    Added file Project/res/values/strings.xml
    Created directory /var/lib/jenkins/Project/res/layout
    Added file Project/res/layout/main.xml
    Added file Project/AndroidManifest.xml
    Added file Project/build.xml
    Added file Project/proguard-project.txt
    jenkins@host:~$ cd Project/
    jenkins@host:~/Project$ ant -d
    Apache Ant version 1.8.0 compiled on M
    ....
     [echo]               unless 'nodeps' is used as well.

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: are you  100% sure that /home/dims/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.0_r2/tools/aapt exists and can be read/executed by the jenkins user?

Answer (score 9):

This peculiar error happens when you attempt to run aapt (or a project that requires it) on a 64 bit system that is lacking some required 32 bit libraries, such as a default Ubuntu > 9. The solution is to install the ia32-libs package with

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Assuming you don't want to install close to 300 packages, run this instead:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386 --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: I would never guessed this! Thanks a lot!! Why this is not accepted as solution?

Comment: I'm guessing @BranGi stopped using StackOverflow.